# PHP session sum cart quantity even different product id

Tags: php, loops, session

I have `session` to add product cart.

```
$getProductID = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['productID']);
    $getQuantity = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['quantity']);

    foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
        $new_product[$key] = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }

    $qProduct = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM tb_product WHERE productid = '" . $getProductID . "'");
    $dProduct = mysqli_fetch_array($qProduct);

    $product_id = $dProduct['productid'];
    $product_name = $dProduct['product_name'];
    $product_price = $dProduct['product_price'];

    $new_product["productid"] = $product_id;
    $new_product["product_name"] = $product_name;
    $new_product["product_price"] = $product_price;
    $new_product["quantity"] = $getQuantity;

    if(isset($_SESSION["products"]))
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION["products"][$new_product['productid']]))
        {
            unset($_SESSION["products"][$new_product['productid']]);
        }           
    }

    $_SESSION["products"][$new_product['productid']] = $new_product;

    $total_items = count($_SESSION["products"]);

    foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product)
    {
        $product_quantity = $product["quantity"];
    }

    die(json_encode(array('items'=>$product_quantity)));
```

Then now I want to get `session` of product quantity

```
foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product)
{
    echo $product_quantity = $product["quantity"];
}
```

I can get the quantity as well, until I try to add another product cart it's not sum the quantity.

Example, on Product1 I add to cart 5pcs (I can see the quantity is 5)
and then I add Product2 to cart 3pc (It show me 53 that should be 8).

My question, how to sum the quantity even Product ID is different?

Comment: Initialize $product_quantity = 0; outside the loop. Then change code to $product_quantity += $product["quantity"];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your loop as below, Sum inside loop and move echo outside of loop.

```
$product_quantity = 0;
foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product)
{
    $product_quantity += $product["quantity"];
}
echo $product_quantity;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think because your coding have something wrong

```
//Incorrect

 foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product)
 {
        echo $product_quantity = $product["quantity"];
 }
 //first loop echo-ed 5
 //second loop echo-ed 3
 //so it show 53

//Correct
$product_quantity = 0;

foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product)
{
   $product_quantity += $product["quantity"];
}

echo $product_quantity;
```